# db row not getting updated

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

i have this input checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="224" onchange="markThisLessonAsCompleted('224');" value="1">
```

and this ajax call :

```
function markThisLessonAsCompleted(lesson_id) {
  $('#lesson_list_area').hide();
  $('#lesson_list_loader').show();
  var progress;
  if ($('input#'+lesson_id).is(':checked')) {
    progress = 1;
  }else{
    progress = 0;
  }
  console.log(progress);
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '<?php echo site_url('user/save_course_progress_new'); ?>',
    data : {lesson_id : lesson_id, progress : progress},
    success : function(response){
      //currentProgress = response;
      console.log(response + "-");
      $('#lesson_list_area').show();
      $('#lesson_list_loader').hide();
    }
  });
}
```

this is the contoller:

```
    function save_course_progress_new() {
        $response = $this->user_model->save_course_progress_new();
        echo $response;
    }
```

and this is the model:

```
      function save_course_progress_new() {
        $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $data['lesson_id'] = $this->input->post('lesson_id');
        $data['done'] = '1';
        $this->db->insert('watch_history', $data);
        return json_encode($data);
      }
```

for some reason the db->insert is not inserting the new row, also the ajax alway outputs in console:

```
(progress) 1/0
(inside the ajax response) -
```

is there anything i am missing ? 

`1. why is the database row not added
2. why the ajax response is empty`

this is the db table structure
[image]

Comment: I never used Codeigniter but maybe this will help you a bit. Try to var_dump() your db connection/ errors most time the db will return why it is not working the way you expect. If you don't use xdebug you can use var dump in your code and then exit to see if your functions are getting the right data

Comment: in fact i went a step forword and comenter the entire controller and added a 
```
return "123"
```
but the ajax still returned empty

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to work with unprocessed input directly in the model, so you should really move that code into controller and then pass it to the model